# Running kitchen test from multiple cookbooks

Tags: chef-infra

Im trying to run test from different cookbooks using just one kitchen.yml file but what seems to be happening is that it just runs the recipes and not the test. is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: test by cooking yourself

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the folder for the tests matches the name of the suite. If you have a `.kitchen.yml` like this:

```
platforms:
- name: ubuntu-12.04
- name: ubuntu-14.04

suites:
- name: default
  run_list:
  - recipe[foo]
  - recipe[baz]
- name: other
  run_list:
  - recipe[bar]
```

Then tests would go under `test/integration/default/` and `test/integration/other/` respectively.